# Как разместить элементы?

Tags: wordpress

Как разместить элементы на странице? Движок WordPress +  Elementor. Пробовал позиционировать виджет call to action, но что-то делаю не так. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день! А что вы пробовали и что не получилось? Добавьте пожалуйста [mre]. Расположить можно с помощью css, svg, canvas, js или на картинке создать карту через `<map>` и `<area>`

Comment: это Elementor. как в нем расположить?

Comment: Скорее всего: - через [добавление своего функционала](https://developers.elementor.com/add-custom-functionality/); или возможно, через html код. Возможно получится через [Motion Effects](https://elementor.com/blog/introducing-motion-effects/)

Answer (score 2):

Все вышло. как  и писал call to action и  `position: absolute;`
ну и родителю `position: relative`;
а потом игра с адаптивностью)))

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).